# How to parse JSON foreach object in array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, parsing, json.net

I'm currently looping through a JSON array and generating an object for each item in the array.

I wondering how I can parse data from the current object.

```
int i = 0, count = 0, yMP, yGP, yGT, favscountB8 = 0;

string gamertag;

JObject o1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"gamerprofile.json"));

            string jsonGamerprofile = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o1);

            var resultObjects = AllChildren(JObject.Parse(jsonGamerprofile))
            .First(c => c.Type == JTokenType.Array && c.Path.Contains("favorites"))
            .Children<JObject>();

        foreach (JObject result in resultObjects)
        {

            // Here I wish to make the string gamertag = the value of (FavsGTS_gpF) which is inside the current object.

            favscountB8 = favscountB8 + 1;
            count = count + 1;
            yMP = 6 + (62 * (count - 1));
            yGP = 7 + (62 * (count - 1));
            yGT = 11 + (62 * (count - 1));

            Panel mainpanel1 = new Panel();
            PictureBox gamerpic1 = new PictureBox();
            Label gamertag1 = new Label();

            mainpanel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            mainpanel1.Location = new Point(6, yMP);
            mainpanel1.Size = new Size(957, 60);
            mainpanel1.Name = "mainpanel" + i.ToString();

            gamerpic1.BackColor = Color.Azure;
            gamerpic1.Location = new Point(7, yGP);
            gamerpic1.Size = new Size(54, 54);
            gamerpic1.Name = "gamerpic" + i.ToString();
            gamerpic1.BringToFront();

            gamertag1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(110, 120, 127);
            gamertag1.BackColor = Color.White;
            gamertag1.Text = "Gamertag " + count.ToString();
            gamertag1.Font = new Font("Arial Narrow", 14, FontStyle.Bold);
            gamertag1.Location = new Point(76, yGT);
            gamertag1.Size = new Size(145, 23);
            gamertag1.Name = "Gamertag " + count.ToString();
            gamertag1.BringToFront();


            i = i + 1;
            panel4.Controls.Add(gamertag1);
            panel4.Controls.Add(gamerpic1);
            panel4.Controls.Add(mainpanel1);

        }
```

Inside the foreach statement I wish to make the "gamertag" string equal to the value of "FavsGTS_gpF" which is in each object in the array.

Comment: why not create a class for your object and use json.net to serialize the json?

Comment: JanR has the only valid approach. If you already have a sample JSON, you can, in Visual STudio, simply go to the edit meny, choose "Paste Special" and "Paste Json as class" - it does not get simpler, really.

Comment: Why do you parse the JSON to a JObject, serialize it back to a string and then parse it back to a JObject again?